# Ensure users click links that are seen as worse than they actually are

Tags: feature-request

Look, I think a lot of us can agree, we might have linked to W3Schools, and then get instantly downvoted, and receive a link to W3Fools, without any explanation of what you did wrong. Maybe we could implement a small feature that ensures users click links that they misleadingly see as "bad".

EDIT: Okay,  there is probably a definable list of sites that are seen as "bad", but are actually perfectly reasonable. Then they suggest MDN because they think it's better, despite essentially being wikipedia, but for code.

This needs to stop.

Comment: Regardless of whether or not this is a good idea, how could it even be possible?

Comment: @Don'tPanic it's easy, man. Just auto redirect from the answer, skipping  it altogether.

Comment: _"Look, I think a lot of us can agree, we might have linked to W3Schools ..."_ Probably not. Why someone should be forced to click your obviously foolish links before downvoting your post as crap?

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ Maybe it isn't foolish. Look, whatever you heard about W3Schools is outdated. Maybe, next time you see one of those links, you should click it.

Comment: Since links are supposed to be secondary sources of info (or more details), I can't see why it would be necessary to read the link before judging the quality of the answer.

Comment: @hellol11 To elaborate: [_W3Schools_](http://www.w3schools.com/) is widely considered a bad resource when referring to solutions as I've experienced here. Still.

Comment: Ouch!  The pigs are flying low tonight:(  I must search high and low for dubious links to explore.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ from what I have learned, widely believed does not translate to fact. Again, click a link, count the errors. You will be impressed.

Comment: @MartinJames Caught one. It's on the barbecue now. Waiting :-P ...

Comment: @psubsee2003 because those links are downvoted *on sight*.

Comment: @hellol11 Well, regardless of acceptance of that linked resource, what's your concrete feature request actually?

Comment: We have to downvote them.  It's not possible to hide them or blow them up, so downvoting is all that's available.

Comment: @hellol11 why do you assume they were downvoted because of the source?

Comment: @psubsee2003 To be honest, it's actually likely.

Comment: I am glad that Stack Overflow does not force me to click on links, and I am _very_ glad that it is not able to analyze my perception of the value of links.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ simple. ensure users click the link before they can do anything else. Solves the number one problem of any answer containing one of the described links: they get downvoted *on sight*.

Comment: What, ' ensure users click the link before they can do anything else',..... you trolleth, surely?

Comment: @Don't Panic It can look at the link, and it doesn't have to analyze it. It's pretty easy to construct a list of generally downvoted links.

Comment: @Martin James I'm not trolling, i'm serious. Apparently, at the mention of W3Schools, i'm getting downvoted. It's that bad.

Comment: I'm happy to be forced to click on links,  I just want $10,000,000 in escrow in case I end up somewhere I don't want to be.

Comment: @psubsee2003 who said I was assuming? There are topics on stack exchange meta that discuss, specifically, how those links get downvoted on sight.

Comment: @MartinJames no, it's just the ones that are downvoted on sight for no (still) valid reason.

Comment: I genuinely like this idea. Too many people will unhelpfully slag W3Schools, without offering alternatives, or without actually comparing whether the alternative has relevant information that W3Schools does. I'm no fan of them, either, but the way people respond on Stack Overflow is often unconstructive.

Comment: @Jeremy Banks agreed.

Comment: @MartinJames Chime in on my answer to improve it?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I see nothing wrong with it, it's a good manual solution.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I upvoted it, but I don't think that 'No' can be improved upon:)

Comment: @MartinJames I found a way to improve myself. Anyway I was calling you since there was a silly initial DV on my answer.

Comment: @JeremyBanks _"I genuinely like this idea."_ You can't be serious?!? Actually regardless if W3Schools should be considered as a good resource or not.

Comment: Without at least single example of _good complete_ answer with downvotes due to link to W3Schools it is very hard to consider this real feature request.

Comment: "*whatever you heard about W3Schools is outdated*". [Ehem](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34530852/1529630), [ehem](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35370441/1529630), [ehem](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36842679/1529630). The only outdated thing is W3Schools.

Comment: [Note question discussion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322276/what-can-mere-mortal-users-do-to-push-a-feature-request-getting-the-status-de)

Comment: That is a thoroughly insane proposal.

Comment: @Oriol that's one case out of how many?

Comment: @hellol11 This case demonstrates W3Schools didn't care to update their blatantly wrong and misleading article for at least 4 months (probably much longer). This has confused at least 3 different SO users, and probably many more people. And I remember seeing several similar cases. W3Schools is not a wiki and doesn't participate in W3C standards, so it can't be as good as MDN. That said, IMO W3schools doesn't always deserve a downvote, but people is free to downvote according to whatever criteria they want (except serial downvoting).

Comment: @Oriol no, MDN is the wiki

Comment: @Oriol I can confirm, when I got an account, it told me that I could edit pages.

Comment: Exactly, I said "W3Schools is not a wiki". Since MDN is a wiki, it's more updated.

Comment: It's also more error-prone, as anyone can edit it.

Comment: even then, it's still massively incomplete, for it's purpose. W3Schools fufills it's purpose just fine, as an introductory site, and quick reference.

Comment: I want you all to say when was the last time you have even been on W3Schools. Have you ever considered what's wrong with W3Fools?

Comment: My last time was like 10 days ago, the "HTML <a> Tag" article (probably I clicked the wrong link in the search engine). The wrong nomenclature in the title itself ("tag" instead of "element") says it all.

Comment: The issue is that w3school is mistaken as a 'definition' rather than an 'intro' by new learners.  I read w3schools every week, but only because I want the simple description or a link to the 'Try it' where I can adapt to my needs.  Its prejudice (elitist) to downvote OP who know less than you, I don't tolerate this in my dev team, and distrust anyone on stackoverflow who I see exhibit this behavour, no matter how much REP they have.

Comment: @miltonb you're just trolling now.  This whole W3Schools question has a bad odour of processed meats.  It's ridiculous request for a crazy feature and deserves its -41 votes.

Comment: @MartinJames actually, he's right. He never said anything about implementing it.

Comment: @MartinJames - Totally against implementing the feature, but the suggestion came from a genuine frustration with being downvoted for mentioning a particular website.  There is no feature that can change that human behavior, but should stop to dream of a better world?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> Maybe we could implement a small feature that ensures users click links ...

**No.**

We don't want any enforcements to read links before taking actions on the posts. That's totally counterproductive.

Any posts on Stack Overflow should be self contained and shouldn't require users to read links before judging usefulness of the post.

Put any essentials of a link into your post as a

> cite
>
> > Maybe we could implement a small feature that ensures users click links that they misleadingly see as "bad"

and put the link as a

[decoration](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322267/ensure-users-click-links-that-are-seen-as-worse-than-they-actually-are)

---

Also think of the ***horror scenario***:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

We'll come over a spam post containing a may be even malicious link, and we are forced to click it (despite seeing it's crap from hovering already) to get that spam post downvoted, closed and deleted.

---

I hope mods come in and clearly mark this feature-request with [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined).

Comment: first, the comments now the answers. while this may be a good solution until this gets implemented (if at all, I do realize how ridiculous this sounds).

Comment: Also, I think it's time that we came down on this issue. There seems to be no good solution besides this.

Comment: Do you remeber me making a comment about it being from a specific list?

Answer (score 17):

> ensure users click the link before they can do anything else.

You say "the link" as though you're posing an answer with a single link. What if it's two links? Or six?

I often link to reference material in my answers, so that people can learn more details about a particular subject. Should users be required to read *every single link* before even so much as *commenting*, let alone voting or accepting the answer? The links are *supplementary material*, not required reading.

Your proposal is extremely poorly thought out. You're trying to fix a problem that results from people not liking one particular website. And your "fix" will impact *every post with links on the site*, whether it involves your website of choice or not. That's absurd.

I get that you feel W3Schools is a reasonable site to link to. I get that you're upset that you get auto-downvoted by people who strongly feel a different way about it. But making a major change to the site is not an effective solution for dealing with a social problem of this nature.