# What can mere mortal users do to push a [feature-request] getting the [status-declined] tag on meta SO?

Tags: support, feature-request, flags, meta-tags

Merely as posted in the title.

Since as stated in the [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) tag wiki

> This tag can be added or removed by moderators and site developers only.

What can users with non moderator privileges do to force moderators attention to meta questions and propose to decline a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)?

There's no appropriate flagging or close reason available (unless custom flags/close reasons where these aren't really useful IMHO).

---

Is it just let the mods♦ and site developers judging by down votes?

... and maybe giving an explaining answer like these

> [Reward More Reputation to Correct Answers for Up Voted Questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322272/reward-more-reputation-to-correct-answers-for-up-voted-questions/322274#322274)
>
> [Ensure users click links that are seen as worse than they actually are](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322267/ensure-users-click-links-that-are-seen-as-worse-than-they-actually-are/322269#322269)

Should we provide an answer why such feature should not be implemented (in our humble opinions)?

Comment: Same motivation, and hey, got status declined http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/263662/213575

Comment: @Braiam OK, interesting insight.

Comment: If I were a mod I would so put [status-declined] on this. ;)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

If it's already heavily downvoted, then there's really no reason to worry about it.

It's extremely unlikely that a feature with mass downvotes on it will get implemented, and bothering moderators with flags just to add a status-declined tag to something that should clearly be declined is just noise.

They'll add it if they see it and want to add it, otherwise there's no real point.

Not every single [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) *needs* to have a [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) tag on it - the tag only clarifies that it won't happen, and is more useful for stuff that *did* get community support behind it.

Comment: Thanks for providing the hindsight. So at least downvoting and give a good reasoning why a feature-request shouldn't be implemented in an answer, is the correct reaction?

Comment: But, but... I can get tag badges for counter arguments against FR's!

Comment: @Braiam _"I can get tag badges for counter arguments against FR's!"_ Links to badges and how these are gained? Just participating in the FR tag and provide upvoted answers?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/249951/help-us-test-the-shiny-new-user-activity-page-plus-a-bunch-of-new-features?#comment816082_249951

Comment: What about [feature requests which aren't massively downvoted](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/316208/1079354), but are rejected?  Is there some recourse for those?

Answer (score 19):

In addition to what Animuson said:

> Should we provide an answer why such feature should not be implemented?

Yes. If you think that something should not be implemented, and it is getting some support among users, by all means explain why you think it should not be implemented. Meta is for discussing issues, not merely praising ideas.

That doesn't mean anyone will agree with you. But a reasoned argument is is pretty much all you have, beyond voting.